# Prompt does not appear when doing Cmd.cmdloop()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this minimalist example to try `cmd2`

```
from cmd2 import Cmd                 

class App(Cmd):                      
    def __init__(self, name='world'):
        Cmd.__init__(self)           
        self.name = name             

    def do_printhello(self):         
        print('hello ' + self.name)      

a = App()                            
a.cmdloop()
```

I would expect the prompt to appear when running this, but nothing happens :

```
$ ./test.py
$
```

Comment: How did you install `cmd2`? I could reproduce this using the unmodified (python2) source with python3. You either need to use the correct egg, or build it your self (possibly through pip), which will apply the 2to3 fixes.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I installed it from an AUR archlinux package (python-cmd2). Installed it from pip and i works now.